# Increasing number of concurrent tasks in NIFI not improving performance

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I have an ExecuteStreamCommand processor which executes a Python script. This takes a long time to execute ~ 5 mins. So I increased the number of concurrent tasks from 1, 4 and 8 but this had. no impact on the performance. I have an 8 core Intel i9 Mac machine with 32 GB RAM. I read that typically the number of concurrent tasks is roughly equal to  2 or 4 times the cores. Could you let me know why there is no improvement? How can I improve the performance?

Thanks

Ganesh

Comment: it really depends on what the tasks are, if they are all IO bound then you will not get any improvement. in this case, if they are all trying to read large data from the same disk then you wont get anything from concurrency

Comment: @nullman - It is more processing intensive and not IO intensive. YAML files have to be read and then massaged appropriately  to create a dataframes.It would appear that increasing concurrent tasks would greatly improve performance. But it doesn't

Comment: @TinniamV.Ganesh  how many processors do you have in your nifi? how many total threads have you set for nifi?

Comment: @daggett - There are a total of 8 processors in the flow. However for testing I was running the ExecuteStreamCommand singly to see if changing concurrent value was having any effect. It did not. Also I tried to change the interval to a large value 15 mins. It did not help

Comment: if you set concurrency=2 (for example) - are they running in parallel but twice slowly?

Comment: No it does not run slowly. It takes the same amount of time ~5mins for (1,4,8 concurrent tasks)

Comment: It appears (based on reported behavior) that you have created multiple tasks but assigned them all to the same thread. This isn't the parallel computing paradigm you're going for. This executes tasks concurrently within the same thread, but since each task is blocking, it's effectively not parallelized. Explicitly each task to a new thread and you should see improvement.

Comment: maybe stupid but did you have multiple flowfile in input of the processor ?

Answer (score 0):

> No it does not run slowly. It takes the same amount of time ~5mins for (1,4,8 concurrent tasks) – Tinniam V. Ganesh Mar 3 at 16:07

That is to be expected because NiFi and the Java VM cannot loan out threads to your Python script to use. The concurrency settings there are for how many threads NiFi is allowed to assign to the processor. Each thread will fire up a new instance of your process. The only way to make your script run faster is to work on the script itself.